# Primereact Styling Conflict with MUI JOY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, primereact

[this is image datatables and button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9AEM.png)

I'm using Primereact and mui joy at the same project, but Primereact styling won't load properly.
I don't know if because conflict with MUI JOY or no

here my package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-collection-sys",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.18",
    "@mui/joy": "5.0.0-beta.15",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.153",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.18",
    "primereact": "^10.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-paginate": "^8.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.20.0",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.15",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.53.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.4",
    "vite": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

and this my line code for component

```
import React from "react";
import { PrimeReactProvider, PrimeReactContext } from 'primereact/api';
import { DataTable } from 'primereact/datatable';
import { Column } from 'primereact/column';

// STYLING
import 'primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css';
import { useState } from "react";

function Datatables() {
  const [isData, setIsData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'try',
      text: 'try again'
    }
  ])
  return (
    <>
      <PrimeReactProvider>
        <DataTable
          value={isData}
          paginator
          rows={5}
          removableSort
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50]}
          tableStyle={{ minWidth: '50rem' }}
        >
          <Column 
            field="title"
            header="Title"
            sortable
            style={{ width: '25%' }}
          />
        </DataTable>
      </PrimeReactProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default Datatables;
```

even render button can't render properly, and in Primereact ver 10 no more import for

```
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.css'; // core css
/**
 * The primereact[.min].css has been deprecated. In order not to break existing projects, it is currently included in the build as an empty file.
 */
```

and i already import resources theme
`import "primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css";`

before that i have project build with MUI JOY and primereact for testing datatables and work properly, why this one can't render properly?

Answer (score 1):

It does conflict because it PR 10+ they introduced CSS Layers.

```css
@layer primereact {
```

These layers now get ordered differently with how browsers interpret CSS and the order.  You can see others have this issue as well and you might want to subscribe to this GitHub Issue Ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/5124

Also this explains it as well: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/4987

Comment: Thank you for answer, because i have custom css in other file like `*{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }` so primereact can't render properly. I already delete that line and primereact work properly